# JConsole plugins in Java Mission Control

Tags: java, jmc

I have installed the Coherence Tab Pack and Twitter Action console plugins to the Oracle Java mission Control. But when I open the Console, it says:

> No plug-ins available! Could not create the Plugin tab.
>
> Make sure to set the JConsole plug-ins directory in preferences to point to a directory where you have JConsole plugins.
>
> The error was: Could not find anz valid plug-ins in C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_40\lib\missioncontrol\plugins. Please check the plug-in path in the preferences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to set the path in Window -> Preferences -> Java Mission Control -> JMX Console -> JConsole Plug-in to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_40\demo\management\JTop, restart the JMX Console and look at the Other group in the large vertical toolbar?

You should se the JTop plug-in or a message explaining why there are no JConsole plug-ins.

Comment: Well, I don't have the /demo directory in my JDK instalation. Yes, the error I have described above shows up when I click on the 'Other' tool item. I thought I should set path to a directory containing JConsole plugins (in my case the Coherence Tab Pack and Twitter Action console plugins). But I'm apparently missing the point here.

Comment: I think you need to check "Demos and samples" (or something similar)  when you install the JDK (to get the demo folder). The JConsole plug-in is a meta plug-in that allows you to run old JConsole plug-ins. Twitter/Coherence are Eclipse based plug-ins, they will install automatically in Mission Control, no need to point out missioncontrol/plugins folder.